# MySql Signal definition

Tags: mysql, signals

When defining a signal in a mySql stored procedure, is the sqlstate value representative of the error condition in that stored procedure, or is the value representative across the database?

Comment: Not sure what you are getting at an error might be triggered by something in the procedure and that error may have knock on effects down the line (in a script of which the procedure is part). Please try to clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  SIGNAL Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/signal.html)

> SIGNAL provides error information to a handler, to an outer portion of the application, or to the client.

In other words, the SIGNAL statement acts within the call tree within a connection.